# Prior art request: A system and method for controlling a service station related to a vehicle

Tags: prior-art-request, us20180018649, self-service, car-wash

In reference to the patent application: [US20180018649](https://www.google.com/patents/US20180018649)

**Independent claims**

> **1.  A system** for controlling a service station related to a vehicle, comprising
>
> a user interface element (10) comprising an app
>   installed in a user apparatus (20);
>
> an identification element (30);
>
> a control element (40) connected to the service station;
>
> and a back-end
>   element (50);
>
> wherein the identification element (30) is configured to
>   retrieve identifying information and to send it to the back-end
>   element (50);
>
> the back-end element (50) is configured to enable via
>   the control element (40) the use of the service station based on the
>   identifying information;
>
> and wherein the user interface element (10)
>   after receiving an authentication of an access right from the back-end
>   element (50) is configured to enable the user to start a service of
>   the service station.
>
> **10. A method** for controlling a service station related to a vehicle, comprising
>
> initiating a user interface element (10)
>   comprising an app installed in a user apparatus (20);
>
> retrieving
>   identifying information with an identification element (30);
>
> authenticating an access right on the basis of the identifying
>   information with a back-end element (50);
>
> enabling the use of the
>   service station via a control element (40);
>
> enabling the user to start
>   a service of the service station via the user interface element (10)
>   after receiving an authentication of an access right from the back-end
>   element (50).

Comment: I attempted to format the claims to be more readable.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I kind of doubt this will get get issued as a patent. It seems abstract and fairly obvious.

Comment: You may be right. But sometimes, as we know, obvious solutions may get patent granted also. This is software related application, perhaps I should ask form some other StackExchange community also :)

Comment: It is getting harder and harder to get claims like these patented in the U.S. However, there is plenty of time in the prosecution of the patent application to amend the claims to something less abstract as long as there is support with enough details in the specification.